# Remove keyword from $http.get JSON call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Let me preface this by saying I'm a beginner and overall noob with Angular and JSON calls.

I'm doing a $http.get call to a JSON object(?) and it looks like this:

```
[{
path: "site:images/gallery/1238.jpg",
data: {
    caption: "",
    url: ""
}
}, {
    path: "site:images/gallery/abelone.jpg",
    data: {
        caption: "",
        url: ""
    }
}, {
    path: "site:images/gallery/carrot.jpg",
    data: {
        caption: "",
        url: ""
    }
}, {
    path: "site:images/gallery/cream.jpg",
    data: {
        caption: "",
        url: ""
    }
}, {
    path: "site:images/gallery/img_2679.jpg",
    data: {
        caption: "",
        url: ""
    }
}, {
    path: "site:images/gallery/img_4908.jpg",
    data: {
        caption: "",
        url: ""
    }
}]
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
$http.get('/_admin/index.php/rest/api/galleries/get/Restaurant?token=xxx')
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.gallery = response.data;
});
```

And with an ng-repeat:

```
<article ng-repeat="item in gallery">
    <p>{{item.path}}</p>
</article>
```

What I need is to somehow remove the `site:` keyword from each `path` "record".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response.data.path returns together with "site:" prefix in string, nothing to do with $http call, so it's just simple string operation. Try this:

```
<article ng-repeat="item in gallery">
    <p>{{ item.path.slice(5) }}</p>
</article>
```